# Trying to change value using JavaScript for homework

Tags: javascript, checkbox, attributes

I am trying to change the value of an attribute using JavaScript. So, in a nutshell, I need to make this so if the checkbox is checked, then the info in the shipping name and zip inputs is copied to the billing name and zip inputs. I have checked the console and it is not giving me much information. Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you! :)

```js
function billingFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("same").checked) {
    var billName = document.getElementById('billingName');
    var billZip = document.getElementById('billingZip');
    return document.getElementById('shippingName').value.innerHTML = billName.value;
    return document.getElementById('shippingZip').value.innerHTML = billZip.value;
  } else {
    let billName = '';
    let billZip = '';
  }


}
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>JavaScript Homework</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/shippingBilling.css">
  <script src="js/billingFunction.js"></script>
</head>
<h1>JavaScript Homework</h1>
<p>Add the JavaScript code needed to enable auto-complete on this form. Whenever the checkbox is checked, the code should automatically copy the values from Shipping Name and Shipping Zip into the Billing Name and Billing Zip. If the checkbox is unchecked,
  the Billing Name and Billing Zip should go blank.</p>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
    <label for="shippingName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="shipName" id="shippingName" required><br/>
    <label for="shippingZip">Zip code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="shipZip" id="shippingZip" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" onchange="billingFunction()">
  <label for="same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Billing Information</legend>
    <label for="billingName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billName" id="billingName" required><br/>
    <label for="billingZip">Zip code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billZip" id="billingZip" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Verify" />
</form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues

- Don't use return where you do. Return leaves the function immediately
- It is .value, not .value.innerHTML
- This code does nothing useful:

  ```
  let billName = '';
  let billZip = '';
  ```

```js
const billName = document.getElementById('billingName');
const billZip = document.getElementById('billingZip');
const shipName = document.getElementById('shippingName')
const shipZip = document.getElementById('shippingZip')
const same = document.getElementById('same');
function billingFunction() {
  if (same.checked) {
    billName.value = shipName.value;
    billZip.value  = shipZip.value;
  }  
  else {
    billName.value = "";
    billZip.value  = "";
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>JavaScript Homework</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/shippingBilling.css">
  <script src="js/billingFunction.js"></script>
</head>
<h1>JavaScript Homework</h1>
<p>Add the JavaScript code needed to enable auto-complete on this form. Whenever the checkbox is checked, the code should automatically copy the values from Shipping Name and Shipping Zip into the Billing Name and Billing Zip. If the checkbox is unchecked,
  the Billing Name and Billing Zip should go blank.</p>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
    <label for="shippingName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="shipName" id="shippingName" required><br/>
    <label for="shippingZip">Zip code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="shipZip" id="shippingZip" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" onchange="billingFunction()">
  <label for="same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Billing Information</legend>
    <label for="billingName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billName" id="billingName" required><br/>
    <label for="billingZip">Zip code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billZip" id="billingZip" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Verify" />
</form>

</html>
```

Also you can use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
function billingFunction() {
  const isSame = same.checked;
  billName.value = isSame ? shipName.value : "";
  billZip.value = isSame ? shipZip.value : "";
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, the course I am in is a very basic course and I have not heard of ternaries before now. As this is the final homework in the class, I am thinking I should stick with "if, else" statements that we have learned.

Comment: @Melanie Ok, I have changed to if/else